# Does a Time-driven trigger run when the spreadsheet is closed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Really new at all of this, and trying to work out whether a trigger I set for between 5 and 6 am will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It will run regardless of whether the spreadsheet is open or closed.